# How do I redirect domains on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, heroku

I have an app designed for multiple users on stuff.heroku.com

A landing page might look like stuff.heroku.com/controller/1/action/73

But the URL that I want to redirect there looks like sub.domain.com/hello

Similarly, I may want sub.domain.com/greetings to point to another landing page, this time at stuff.heroku.com/controller/1/action/74.

Once that works, I will want sub.anotherdomain.com/hello to map back to my same application, such as stuff.heroku.com/controller/1/action/87

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in your application_controller and redirect there.

In Rails 2.3+ you can use rack middleware. Check out the Refraction gem -- it's setup to be a rack replacement for mod_rewrite

https://github.com/pivotal/refraction

```
Refraction.configure do |request|
  if req.host == 'sub.domain.com'
    req.rewrite! "http://sub.domain.com/#{req.path}"
  end
end
```

The above will just take people from stuff.heroku.com to sub.domain.com -- but you could easily do your /hello rewrite if you want.

Comment: I see...how do I do it in Rails 2.3?

Comment: Updated my answer.... rack middleware will work in 2.3, so you should be good to go

Comment: super, thanks, I thought it might be but wasn't sure....I will give ue a +1 for your answer o the question.  I have a quick another question: can the rewrite paths come from a value put into a database, such as the method of a record?  So a user can select their path?

Comment: @Angela -- that could happen, but you probably would want that to happen at the application_controller level. At the rack level you don't have DB connections setup yet, so it'd be more trouble than it's worth.