# How to redirect http:// to http://www on Heroku using Play framework and Scala

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework-2.0

I saw it is possible to redirect http:// to [http://www] on Heroku using Rails, as explained in [Heroku how to redirect http:// to http://www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389575/heroku-how-to-redirect-http-to-http-www).

Is it (already) possible to do it using Scala and Play 2?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Not much. I hoped it could be done directly using the framework...

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with Play directly, but the best solution to this problem is in the very same question you linked. You should solve this [on the DNS level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12325021/772743).

Comment: I see. And do I need to buy the www domain then to be able to do the redirection www.myapp.herokuapp.com -> http://myapp.herokuapp.com?