# Django 301 Domain Redirect for Heroku

Tags: django, redirect, heroku

It seems Google has managed to spider some of my heroku apps pages on the app sub domain i.e. myapp.herokuapp.com. I need to do a 301 redirect so all these pages point to the actual apps domain www.myapp.com

Any idea how I do this in Django? I see the redirect app only works for 404s so this won't be any good, and all the examples for RedirectView are for the domain path.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Heroku how to redirect http:// to http://www](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5389575/heroku-how-to-redirect-http-to-http-www)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Django Hostname redirects](https://github.com/MidwestCommunications/django-hostname-redirects) app and its middleware.

Comment: This worked for me, but I needed to patch https://github.com/MidwestCommunications/django-hostname-redirects/blob/master/hostname_redirects/middleware.py to use request.META['HTTP_HOST'] instead of request.META['SERVER_NAME'] – the server name is always set to "0.0.0.0" on Heroku.